# How to parse PDF content to database with powershell

Tags: parsing, pdf, powershell, extract

I have a pdf document that I would like to extract content out of. The issue I am having is this... I search for the IMEI keyword, and it finds it, but I need the actual IMEI value which is the next item in the loop.

In the PDF the value looks like this:
IMEI 90289393092

returning value via the below script:
-0.1 -8.8 9.8 -0.1 446.7 403.9 Tm (IMEI:) Tj

I only want to have the value:
90289393092

Script I am using:

```
Add-Type -Path .\itextsharp.dll
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList "$pwd\PDF\DOC001.pdf"

for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++) {
 $lines = [char[]]$reader.GetPageContent($page) -join "" -split "`n"
 foreach ($line in $lines) {
  if ($line -match "IMEI") { 
   $line = $line -replace "\\([\S])", $matches[1]
   $line -replace "^\[\(|\)\]TJ$", "" -split "\)\-?\d+\.?\d*\(" -join ""

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: If it's a regex problem, it would help to know what the raw text in the file looks like. How it's rendered by the application doesn't help much.

Answer (score 4):

this is the way for using itextsharp.dll and read a pdf as plain text:

```psh
Add-Type -Path .\itextsharp.dll
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList c:\ps\a.pdf        

for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++)
{
    $strategy = new-object  'iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy'            
    $currentText = [iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($reader, $page, $strategy);
    [string[]]$Text += [system.text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Text.ASCIIEncoding]::Convert( [system.text.encoding]::default  , [system.text.encoding]::UTF8, [system.text.Encoding]::Default.GetBytes($currentText)));      
}
$Reader.Close();
```

And this can be the regex you need but I haven't tested it

```psh
[regex]::matches( $text, '(?<=IMEI\s+)(\d+)(?=\s+)' ) | select -expa value
```

Comment: Your suggestion finds "IMEI" without issues, thank you. However, I am still having issues capturing the next value which is the actual IMEI number. I am stuck trying figure out how to capture the next variable after the IMEI is found.

Comment: @user2219768 I can't help more of this man, It's hard give the full solution without have the original file, you need try and try again by yourself.

Comment: understood. Thanks for the help.  It looks as if the conversion from PDF is removing all line returns. So, when I find the IMEI it returns the entire string.... the entire file.

Comment: Take care when using itextsharp as its licensed under AGPL which basically means that you have to release your source code publicly. This can be a problem in commercial settings